# Identify users by google-play account

Tags: android, google-play, identity, uniqueidentifier, imei

**Hello,**

I am just developing for fun, and new to android and java.

The users of my app should stay anonymous, but to prevent any bots or spam, i need to identify the user of the app.In order to prevent any abuse.

**I need to have a unique ID** for people using my app, since the app should be available **for both phones and tablets ( having only wifi) IMEI isn't a solution**, and since **users may use 3G to connect and disable the wifi instead, the Mac adresse isn't reliable too** i guess.

I thought that maybe the **google-play account** would be the best solution. if someone changes his phone he would have the same google-play account (especially if he is buying the app).

**My Questions :**

**1-** what do you think about how i tried to solve my problem.

**2-** if my reasoning is good, how can i retrieve the google-play account used to install the app.

**thank you in advance guys.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to install an app in Android, you need to have a Google Play account. So, your reasoning is correct.

You can use the Gmail id as the unique identifier. This is how you get the Gmail Id:

```
public static String getGmailId() {
    String gmailId = "";
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(MyApplicationUtil.getAppContext()).getAccountsByType("com.google");

    for (Account account : accounts) {
        gmailId = account.name;
    }
    return gmailId;
}
```